# How to keep JQuery slideToggle down on ASP postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a very simple slideToggle. Opens and closes just fine. I have some tools, a few drop downs that cause a Post Back. When the post back executes, it causes the slideToggle to go back up. How do I keep that from happening? Is there a default value setting I missed or don't know?

I have searched high and low for this answer and nothing works. I have tried so many different options and all lead to nothing. All the answers given here on the site don't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks again for the help

Here is the slideToggle code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Flip").click(function () {
            $(".FlipPanel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    }); `enter code here`
</script>
```

Here is the markup I use to open and expand.. With some CSS to style it.

```
<div class="Flip" id="testFlip" runat="server">Preferred Cargo</div>
<div class="FlipPanel">

</div>
```

Comment: PostBack means that the page is reloaded, so any javascript/jquery will be reset to their default settings or values. If you want to track the toggle you need to store it somewhere, and set the values again when the PostBack is done. This can be a Cookie or a Hidden Field.

Comment: Thanks VDWWD. I have tried the Hidden Field approach with no success.  At least the idea's posted here. Any idea how I might approach it?

Answer (score 1):

Here a very basic example. The value of `state` will be loaded from the TextBox, incremented and then stored again. You will find that the value increments on every PostBack without server side code. Adapt this to store the open state of your panel.
I uses a TextBox to visualize the process, but normally you would use a HiddenField.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var state = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val();
        state++;
        $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val(state);
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```